# How can I set a sub folder as a root for my website?

Tags: apache

I have a site, currently the root is the default for my website(sample.com), I have two folders such as [public] and [admin].
Now the default address for [public] is -> sample.com/public
and [admin] is -> sample.com/admin

but I want to point [public] folder to sample.com

How can i do that. please help.

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your httpd.conf and add/edit this line to your desired root directory

```
DocumentRoot "public_html/public/"
```

Use chmod to set appropriate permission if needed then restart your apache server :)

Comment: Mine is shared hosting, and cant i do that with .htaccess file

Comment: If you don't have direct access to the configuration file you should try contact the support from your host.